# update error for kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

```
root@axy:~# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
Err:1 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 5):

**Issue:**
Error shows

```
Err:1 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
```

We understand the repository is `http://repo.kali.org/kali`

Now I try to open the link using firefox, I see, "You don't have permission to access /kali on this server" (http://repo.kali.org/kali)

[image]

**Solution 1:**

Try using `https` repository by executing the following command

```
echo "deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then try `sudo apt-get update` If you find the same error, please choose another solution.

**Solution 2:** please execute the following command.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

Then try `sudo apt-get update` If you find the same error, please choose another solution.

**Solution 3:** Please keep a back up file before changing the `sources.list` file Using text editor add these lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then try `sudo apt-get update` If you find the same error, please choose another solution.

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, then please accept this answer by clicking the accept button.

Comment: Solution 1 worked